# Unable to auto accept Room - Meeting Exchange 2013

Tags: outlook, resources, exchange-server

I've been working on this for the last couple of day and I'm out of ideas.

I have two rooms, both reasonably new rooms as well. Both need to auto accept meetings when free and let the delegate action meetings that are not.

Any ideas?

**Here is the one that does not auto accept:**

```
AddAdditionalResponse : False

AdditionalResponse: <DIV><FONT face=Tahoma size=2></FONT></DIV>

AddNewRequestsTentatively           : False

AddOrganizerToSubject               : True

AllBookInPolicy                     : True

AllowConflicts                      : False

AllowRecurringMeetings              : True

AllRequestInPolicy                  : False

AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False

AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept

BookingWindowInDays                 : 365

BookInPolicy                        : {}

ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0

DeleteAttachments                   : True

DeleteComments                      : True

DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True

DeleteSubject                       : False

EnableResponseDetails               : True

EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : False

ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True

Identity                            : corporate.MyDomain/Organisation/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room

IsValid                             : True

MailboxOwnerId                      : corporate.MyDomain/Organisation/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room

MaximumConflictInstances            : 0

MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440

ObjectState                         : Changed

OrganizerInfo                       : True

ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False

RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False

RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True

RemovePrivateProperty               : True

RequestInPolicy                     : {}

RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {/O=My Domain/OU=CORPORATE/cn=Recipients/cn=GROUP-Delegates}

ResourceDelegates                   : {corporate.mydomain/Groups/DistributionLists/GROUP-Delegates}

ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False

TentativePendingApproval            : False
```

**And the one that is working just fine:**

```
AddAdditionalResponse               : False

AdditionalResponse                  : 

AddNewRequestsTentatively           : False

AddOrganizerToSubject               : True

AllBookInPolicy                     : True

AllowConflicts                      : False

AllowRecurringMeetings              : True

AllRequestInPolicy                  : False

AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False

AutomateProcessing                  : AutoAccept

BookingWindowInDays                 : 365

BookInPolicy                        : {}

ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0

DeleteAttachments                   : True

DeleteComments                      : True

DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True

DeleteSubject                       : False

EnableResponseDetails               : True

EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : False

ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True

Identity                            : 
corporate.My Domain/Organization/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Meeting Room F6

IsValid                             : True

MailboxOwnerId                      : corporate.My Domain/Organisation/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Meeting Room F6

MaximumConflictInstances            : 0

MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440

ObjectState                         : Changed

OrganizerInfo                       : True

ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False

RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False

RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True

RemovePrivateProperty               : True

RequestInPolicy                     : {}

RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {}

ResourceDelegates                   : {corporate.my domain/Organization/AdminBuilding/Aimee, 
                                      corporate.my domain/Organization/Natalie}

ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False

TentativePendingApproval            : False
```

And the problem rooms mail account settings:

```
RunspaceId                             : b097d9c5-e6a3-4bbe-a31a-4391011bc914
Database                               : SG02
MailboxProvisioningConstraint          : 
MailboxProvisioningPreferences         : {}
UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults           : False
RetainDeletedItemsUntilBackup          : True
DeliverToMailboxAndForward             : False
IsExcludedFromServingHierarchy         : False
IsHierarchyReady                       : True
LitigationHoldEnabled                  : False
SingleItemRecoveryEnabled              : False
RetentionHoldEnabled                   : False
EndDateForRetentionHold                : 
StartDateForRetentionHold              : 
RetentionComment                       : 
RetentionUrl                           : 
LitigationHoldDate                     : 
LitigationHoldOwner                    : 
LitigationHoldDuration                 : Unlimited
ManagedFolderMailboxPolicy             : 
RetentionPolicy                        : 
AddressBookPolicy                      : 
CalendarRepairDisabled                 : False
ExchangeGuid                           : a008111a-0bfc-4286-a394-8f9e16102413
MailboxContainerGuid                   : 
UnifiedMailbox                         : 
MailboxLocations                       : {1;a008111a-0bfc-4286-a394-8f9e16102413;Primary;MyDomain.com;df028da7-e5c6-4b64-9450-6f7c53247c91}
AggregatedMailboxGuids                 : {}
ExchangeSecurityDescriptor             : System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor
ExchangeUserAccountControl             : None
AdminDisplayVersion                    : Version 15.0 (Build 1076.9)
MessageTrackingReadStatusEnabled       : True
ExternalOofOptions                     : External
ForwardingAddress                      : 
ForwardingSmtpAddress                  : 
RetainDeletedItemsFor                  : 00:00:00
IsMailboxEnabled                       : True
Languages                              : {en-AU}
OfflineAddressBook                     : 
ProhibitSendQuota                      : Unlimited
ProhibitSendReceiveQuota               : Unlimited
RecoverableItemsQuota                  : Unlimited
RecoverableItemsWarningQuota           : Unlimited
CalendarLoggingQuota                   : Unlimited
DowngradeHighPriorityMessagesEnabled   : False
ProtocolSettings                       : {}
RecipientLimits                        : Unlimited
ImListMigrationCompleted               : False
IsResource                             : True
IsLinked                               : False
IsShared                               : False
IsRootPublicFolderMailbox              : False
LinkedMasterAccount                    : NT AUTHORITY\SELF
ResetPasswordOnNextLogon               : False
ResourceCapacity                       : 
ResourceCustom                         : {}
ResourceType                           : Room
RoomMailboxAccountEnabled              : True
SamAccountName                         : _meetingsEMR
SCLDeleteThreshold                     : 
SCLDeleteEnabled                       : 
SCLRejectThreshold                     : 
SCLRejectEnabled                       : 
SCLQuarantineThreshold                 : 
SCLQuarantineEnabled                   : 
SCLJunkThreshold                       : 
SCLJunkEnabled                         : 
AntispamBypassEnabled                  : False
ServerLegacyDN                         : /o=MyDomain City /ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=MAIL02
ServerName                             : mail02
UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults               : True
IssueWarningQuota                      : Unlimited
RulesQuota                             : 64 KB (65,536 bytes)
Office                                 : Walker Street Level 2 - P&D Interview Room - Behind front desk, 2nd door on the right
UserPrincipalName                      : _meetingsEMR@corporate.MyDomain.com
UMEnabled                              : False
MaxSafeSenders                         : 
MaxBlockedSenders                      : 
NetID                                  : 
ReconciliationId                       : 
WindowsLiveID                          : 
MicrosoftOnlineServicesID              : 
ThrottlingPolicy                       : 
RoleAssignmentPolicy                   : Default Role Assignment Policy
DefaultPublicFolderMailbox             : corporate.MyDomain.com/Users/PFMailbox2
SharingPolicy                          : Default Sharing Policy
RemoteAccountPolicy                    : 
MailboxPlan                            : 
ArchiveDatabase                        : 
ArchiveGuid                            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ArchiveName                            : {}
JournalArchiveAddress                  : 
ArchiveQuota                           : Unlimited
ArchiveWarningQuota                    : Unlimited
ArchiveDomain                          : 
ArchiveStatus                          : None
ArchiveState                           : None
IsAuxMailbox                           : False
AuxMailboxParentObjectId               : 
ChildAuxMailboxObjectIds               : {}
MailboxRelationType                    : None
RemoteRecipientType                    : None
DisabledArchiveDatabase                : 
DisabledArchiveGuid                    : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
QueryBaseDN                            : 
QueryBaseDNRestrictionEnabled          : False
MailboxMoveTargetMDB                   : SG02
MailboxMoveSourceMDB                   : SG06
MailboxMoveFlags                       : IntraOrg, Pull
MailboxMoveRemoteHostName              : 
MailboxMoveBatchName                   : 
MailboxMoveStatus                      : Completed
MailboxRelease                         : 
ArchiveRelease                         : 
IsPersonToPersonTextMessagingEnabled   : False
IsMachineToPersonTextMessagingEnabled  : True
UserSMimeCertificate                   : {}
UserCertificate                        : {}
CalendarVersionStoreDisabled           : False
ImmutableId                            : 
PersistedCapabilities                  : {}
SKUAssigned                            : 
AuditEnabled                           : False
AuditLogAgeLimit                       : 90.00:00:00
AuditAdmin                             : {Update, Move, MoveToDeletedItems, SoftDelete, HardDelete, FolderBind, SendAs, SendOnBehalf, Create}
AuditDelegate                          : {Update, SoftDelete, HardDelete, SendAs, Create}
AuditOwner                             : {}
WhenMailboxCreated                     : 11/05/2015 1:40:54 PM
SourceAnchor                           : 
UsageLocation                          : 
IsSoftDeletedByRemove                  : False
IsSoftDeletedByDisable                 : False
IsInactiveMailbox                      : False
IncludeInGarbageCollection             : False
WhenSoftDeleted                        : 
InPlaceHolds                           : {}
GeneratedOfflineAddressBooks           : {}
Extensions                             : {}
HasPicture                             : False
HasSpokenName                          : False
AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom                 : {}
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers        : {}
AcceptMessagesOnlyFromSendersOrMembers : {}
AddressListMembership                  : {\Default Global Address List, \All Users, \All Rooms}
Alias                                  : pdinterviewroom
ArbitrationMailbox                     : 
BypassModerationFromSendersOrMembers   : {}
OrganizationalUnit                     : corporate.MyDomain.com/Organisation/Meeting Rooms
CustomAttribute1                       : 
CustomAttribute10                      : 
CustomAttribute11                      : 
CustomAttribute12                      : 
CustomAttribute13                      : 
CustomAttribute14                      : 
CustomAttribute15                      : 
CustomAttribute2                       : 
CustomAttribute3                       : 
CustomAttribute4                       : 
CustomAttribute5                       : 
CustomAttribute6                       : 
CustomAttribute7                       : 
CustomAttribute8                       : 
CustomAttribute9                       : 
ExtensionCustomAttribute1              : {}
ExtensionCustomAttribute2              : {}
ExtensionCustomAttribute3              : {}
ExtensionCustomAttribute4              : {}
ExtensionCustomAttribute5              : {}
DisplayName                            : MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room
EmailAddresses                         : {x500:/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=e25bae069a104f269b5a313c1afb5121-MEETINGS -, 
                                         SMTP:MEETINGS-ExecutiveMeetingRoom@MyDomain.com, smtp:pdinterviewroom@MyDomain.com}
GrantSendOnBehalfTo                    : {corporate.MyDomain.com/Groups/DistributionLists/GROUP-P&D Interview Room Delegates}
ExternalDirectoryObjectId              : 
HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled          : False
LastExchangeChangedTime                : 
LegacyExchangeDN                       : /o=MyDomain City /ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=pdinterviewroom
MaxSendSize                            : Unlimited
MaxReceiveSize                         : Unlimited
ModeratedBy                            : {}
ModerationEnabled                      : False
PoliciesIncluded                       : {}
PoliciesExcluded                       : {{26491cfc-9e50-4857-861b-0cb8df22b5d7}}
EmailAddressPolicyEnabled              : False
PrimarySmtpAddress                     : MEETINGS-ExecutiveMeetingRoom@MyDomain.com
RecipientType                          : UserMailbox
RecipientTypeDetails                   : RoomMailbox
RejectMessagesFrom                     : {}
RejectMessagesFromDLMembers            : {}
RejectMessagesFromSendersOrMembers     : {}
RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled     : False
SimpleDisplayName                      : 
SendModerationNotifications            : Always
UMDtmfMap                              : {emailAddress:6338464739328848363384647666, lastNameFirstName:6338464739328848363384647666, firstNameLastName:6338464739328848363384647666}
WindowsEmailAddress                    : MEETINGS-ExecutiveMeetingRoom@MyDomain.com
MailTip                                : 
MailTipTranslations                    : {}
Identity                               : corporate.MyDomain.com/Organisation/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room
IsValid                                : True
ExchangeVersion                        : 0.20 (15.0.0.0)
Name                                   : MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room
DistinguishedName                      : CN=MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room,OU=Meeting Rooms,OU=Organisation,DC=corporate,DC=MyDomain,DC=COM
Guid                                   : 2f8aab68-23fd-41d0-a9c3-0ece297b016a
ObjectCategory                         : MyDomain.com/Configuration/Schema/Person
ObjectClass                            : {top, person, organizationalPerson, user}
WhenChanged                            : 23/09/2015 2:15:18 PM
WhenCreated                            : 19/10/2010 12:57:56 PM
WhenChangedUTC                         : 23/09/2015 4:15:18 AM
WhenCreatedUTC                         : 19/10/2010 2:57:56 AM
OrganizationId                         : 
Id                                     : corporate.MyDomain.com/Organisation/Meeting Rooms/MEETINGS - Executive Meeting Room
OriginatingServer                      : DCCORP01.corporate.MyDomain.com
ObjectState                            : Unchanged
```

Comment: Sorry fixed the formatting up

Comment: Moved it to another database today but the issue persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if Direct booking has been enabled on the one that isn't working. If you have both direct booking and Auto Accept enabled then this can cause issues, there is a script to detect and remove direct booking on http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/05/09/use-exchange-web-services-and-powershell-to-discover-and-remove-direct-booking-settings.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you, Unfortuntely I checked that out and none of the boxes are ticked. 

Had to run this manually as I have just enough access to manage the environment but not log into the server and run the script.

Comment: The next thing I would try is enabling some tracing http://blogs.technet.com/b/kristinw/archive/2012/10/04/how-to-properly-gather-traces-for-calendaring-issues-including-extra.aspx